# F4V to MP4 via FFMPEG (Bitrate viewer)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have a several F4V that I've captured using Flash media Live Encoder and I need to convert them to MP4s. As I understand F4V are fairly identical to the MP4 format so we used "copy" for the video and audio codec.

This the the FFmpeg command line I used:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i %1 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -loglevel debug -report %1.mp4
```

The command seems to work except I'm using Bitrate Viewer as a quality check (http://www.winhoros.de/docs/bitrate-viewer/) and the resulting MP4s are displaying incorrect information (http://tinyurl.com/nafcozw). In contrast when I review the log from FFmpeg and use MediaInfo the results are accurate, when compared to the source file (F4V). Should I be concerned what Bitrate viewer is displaying or is there another program than I can use to graph the file bitrate?

Hope I made sense, I'm new to FFMPEG so you will have to excuse my lack of understanding. Thanks

Comment: bitrate = file size/duration, so you can perform your own calculations to compare.

Comment: If your file sizes are more or less identical- it should mean the rates have not changed. In any case, a codec copy means you are not re-encoding, so there should not be any difference.